# OTRS:: how to hide customer administration menu item from customer menu

Tags: otrs

I am using OTRS4, I want to know how to hide customer administration menu item from customer menu.

Answer (score 1):

It's not programming-related so it's probably more a question for SuperUser but here goes:

Navigate to Admin > Framework > Frontend::Admin::ModuleRegistration.

If you want to remove the Customer Company Administration item completely, i.e. from the Menu and also from the Admin section, simply uncheck `Frontend::Module###AdminCustomerCompany`.

If you only want to remove it from the navigation bar you can navigate to the same item in SysConfig and remove the section that has the `NavBar: Customer` item by clicking the `-` symbol.